# How to migrate models in production mode with SailsJS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I developed a web application with the MVC **SailsJS** *(Version 1.1.0)* framework, based on node js. I released it in production mode but every time I release an update from development to production I don't know how to do that.

This, because in development I can execute the `sails lift -alter` command that independently modifies the models and adapts them to new modifications, but in production this command is blocked.

What is the best way to take? Should I create scripts in MongoDB where I manually change the collections?

Comment: Super awesome question, I am also very curious. I haven't yet gone to production, but I will be soon.

Comment: I think that question may be expanded to any database since this command is not blocked only for MongoDB. I'm using MySQL, trying to set up a CI/CD pipe, and the migrations are being such a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've readed in StackOverflow and other sites including Sails official documentation you have to edit your database by hand to addapt to your new model changes given:

"All of your models' migration settings are forced to `migrate: 'safe'`. This is a failsafe to protect against inadvertently damaging your production data during deployment." from [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment#?set-the-nodeenv-environment-variable-to-production) in Sails Official Documentation.

Comment: I already tried this way, but when I `lift` sails it shows an error message like this: `Migration alter is not allowed in production`

Comment: Is to avoid you losing your data. So they obligate you updating manually your production database model. If you want to let Sails update your model automatically just run ```sails lift``` once as if you were in a dev environment and after with ```--prod``` flag as always in production.

Comment: I don't understand how to do this by hand, can you please explain.

Comment: At least in my case using mySQL: For example if I have model Pet and I add the attribute weight in development environment, before I upload the new Sails code in production I have to add a new column weight in Mysql using ALTER TABLE in production database given Sails is not going to update/upgrade my datastore to fit the new model

Comment: Yes, the better way is to update your database structure manually and adapt it to the updated models.

Comment: Is there really no way to bypass this? Migrations were half the reason I chose Sails. Rails and other migration tools migrate in PROD, why does Sails make this manual? Are they not confident in Waterline? Now I'm on the path to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the environment in your current terminal session.

-- NOTE -- I do not recommend altering your database in production because you might lose data. Do this at your own risk.

`export NODE_ENV=development` run in the terminal

Then do your thing `sails lift -alter`

The above instructions should do it and when you are done you can revert the environment to production

`export NODE_ENV=production`

Then go back to running your app as you normally do.